Setting Keep Alive Options on a TCP Socket in Kotlin
Is there a way of setting TCP Keep Alive Options on Android (in Kotlin)? Keep Alive itself can be enabled by setting socket.keepAlive to TRUE, but I did not find a straightforward way to set the IDLE_TIMEOUT, INTERVAL and COUNT options.
I found another StackOverflow answer where a way to achieve it is described (for Android 8+) here, but I'm not sure whether it's good practice to do it that way.
As it's possible to enable Keep Alive, is it bad practice to want to customise its Options (as it's not as straightforward)?
